# Syntax error in sql exec count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
declare @message int,@DBName varchar(50)    
set @DBName ='AutoChip'    

exec('select '+@message+'= count(*) from '+@DBname+'.[dbo].[Report List]')    

print @message
```

Getting an error trying to print the count

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

I will pass DBname dynamically, I am using a cursor

Comment: what is the value of @message?

Comment: just it will return the count

Comment: The variable name needs to be part of dynamic SQL you are creating, but it's shouldn't be concated with it.

Comment: **Don't use a cursor** for a count!! Please.......

Comment: if am not concatenating it showing error as must declare the scalar variable.

Comment: @marc_s i have so many DB to get the count of particular table. is there any better way plz suggest !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable name needs to be part of dynamic SQL you are creating, but it's shouldn't be concated with it.
For example, if your variable is of type `varchar` and has value as 'ERROR', resultant query will be

```
select ERROR= count(*) from YOURDBNAME.[dbo].[Report List]
```

so the correct one is below.

```
 exec('select @message= count(*) from '+@DBname+'.[dbo].[Report List]')
```

You need to include variable declaration and initialization in dynamic sql. You cannot set a value of external variable inside a dynamic sql as the context of execution will be different.

Comment: if i pass as string like this 'select @message= count(*) from ' it showing must declare scalar variable "@message".

Comment: You need to include variable declaration as part of dynamic SQL, in that case.

Comment: dynamic variable can you plz explain am not aware of that

Comment: It is dynamic SQL. the string you enclosed in exec() is called dynamicSQL which will be compiled and executed at runtime in different context. So, if you want set value of variable in a dynamicSQL, the declaration and initialization of that variable must present in that dynamicSQL.